# How to edit mesh properties after adding in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh

Right after adding a mesh object to my scene in Blender, in the tools panel appears a really helpful tooltip named "add [mesh name]", well Im sure everyone knows what im talking about. The thing is, I wish to keep editing a mesh **after** i added it, so for example, I add a torus, i edit it's inner radius, I scale it, and then i want to edit its inner radius again. Is there any way to do this? Because once i performed another action, say "scale", the previous tootlip disappears and is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

The panel you are referring to is the operator properties, which can also be accessed in a floating panel by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

The operator properties allows you to adjust the options for the last operation you performed and it is only available for the last action performed. Some small things like rotating the view do not interfere but any editing actions will replace the options shown with their own options.

Comment: Yes indeed that's the name, what I'm asking is how to access the operator panel after another action has been performed. EG: i add a cube, I scale it, if I press F6, the panel that shows up is the scale panel, whilst I wish to access the "add" operator panel.

Comment: As I mentioned it **only shows the options for the last action**, by scaling that then becomes the last action and is the one showing options in the operator properties panel. There is no support for adjusting actions before the last one performed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the panel never shows up again.
However, you can select the object (e.g. torus), enter Edit Mode, switch to Vertex selection and press Alt+S to scale accordingly.
This worked for me. Hope you find it useful.

Still hoping that Blender will make it possible for us to adjust the dimensions that we usually see when adding an object for the first time. We should be able to adjust things at a later time.